# Alternative to a large group of if-statements?

Tags: c, if-statement, embedded, stm32, stm32f4

I have a set of If Statements (a lot of them, around 40), and they each check an input for an embedded board. For some reason, running through the group of statements is really slow.

```
uint32_t INPUT_ARRAY[40];
#define INPUT_X INPUT_ARRAY[0] // input 1 corresponds to the first array slot and so on, easy to call up a specific input.

void main(){
    while(1) // infinite loop for embedded program
    { 
        Read_Inputs(); // input read function

        Write_Outputs(); // output write function

        Logic_Test(); // This is to test out the inputs and outputs on our hardware test rig
    }
}

inline void Logic_Test(void){
    if ( INPUT_1 != 0){
       output_3 |= some_bit // this logic could change
       output_10 |= another_bit 
    }
    if ( INPUT_2 != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit 
    }
    if ( INPUT_3 != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit 
    }
    if ( INPUT_4 != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_X != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change
    }
    if ( INPUT_40 != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit 
    }
}
```

The code is structured like above and from 1 to 40. They are not if-else-if statements though. I would use a switch, but from my knowledge a switch only covers 1 case at a time, and multiple inputs could be on. Is there a faster way of covering all the inputs without using so many ifs?

Additional Info:
We are using the STM32F4 series (F429ZI) clocked at 180 Mhz.

Comment: How about showing about 5+ `if()` to get a better idea of code?  An [mcve]

Comment: Updated to better reflect existing structure.

Comment: Without some relationship/pattern between the various `output_x |= some_bit // this logic could change` lines of code, just loop through all 40.

Comment: *"the group of statements is really slow."* What is the definition of really slow: microseconds, milliseconds, seconds? What type of processor are you using? What's the clock speed? What is the memory mapped I/O access time?

Comment: Have you actually verified that the problem is the `if` statements. Or is most of the time spent in the `Read_Inputs` and `Write_Outputs` functions?

Comment: We did verify that the issue was with the logic section. It takes about 2.62 microseconds per if-statement to run.

Comment: On what processor, at what clock speed?

Comment: What is unclear here is `uint32_t INPUT_ARRAY[40];` instead of a single `uint64_t INPUT_ARRAY;` using 1 bit per input.  Why use `uin32_t` for a boolean test?  To be clear, with a lot more info, this will be a lot of back & forth questions.   Post a [mcve]

Comment: The STM32F4 series (F429ZI) at 180 Mhz

Comment: @chux We were going to use a uint8_t. The Input Data Register is uint32_t, so it ended up that way, despite not needing the extra space. Also, the MCU is 32-bit.

Comment: 2.62 usec @ 180 instructions/usec = 470 instructions per `if` statement. The code you've shown does not explain how you're using 470 instructions per `if` statement.

Comment: That's what is confusing to us. That shouldn't be possible. We commented out all but 1 if-statement and it came out to 614 ns.

Comment: Are you actually setting the same bit for each case?  If so, why aren't you at least using `else if`?

Comment: I would look at the assembly code to see how the `if` statements have been implemented. There's an outside chance that the compiler is doing an actual multiplication to compute the address into the array. That would definitely slow things down.

Comment: The `INPUT_X` macros have no performance advantage over `INPUT_ARRAY[X]`

Comment: @user3386109 : It is probably worse even than that.  A Cortex-M achieves 1.25MIPS/MHz, so 225 instructions/usec.

Comment: It seems to me you are asking the wrong question. (An X-Y problem).  Rather your question should be _why does this code take 2,62us to run?_  because it should not - no amount of optimising your code will solve a performance issue that large, and the problem is not with this code. Are you certain the PLL is running at 180MHz?  Do you know that you are not frequently in the interrupt context and not actually always running the code in question while you are measuring the performance.  Also how are you measuring the performance?That deserves explanation in case your measurement method is flawed.

Comment: I can smell a demo project running on the internal RC oscillator. Clock setup is where? Btw the GPIO hardware might not be able to toggle faster than somewhere around 30 - 100ns, check analog characteristics.

Comment: So we found out several things. The first thing we found was that the pin we were watching to test the speed of our code was on a lower speed Bus (half the speed of the processor) and giving bad results. The second thing we found was that our temporary timing loops were being offset by the 40 if statements. Enough to slow down our input, output, and LED toggle loops. Thanks for the help everyone. Learned a few things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the branches are impacting performance, it might be possible to remove the branches.  For example, if you're setting a single bit, instead of, say:

```
if (INPUT_n != 0) {
   output_x |= (1 << 15);
}
```

you could unconditionally do:

```
output_x |= ((INPUT_n != 0) << 15);
```

And if you're setting the *same* bit for each input, it could be collapsed into:

```
output_x |= (((INPUT_1 | INPUT_2 | INPUT_3 | ... ) != 0) << 15);
```

Comment: First of all `output_x |= ((INPUT_n != 0) << 15);`  does not change the output_x bit. it can only set it but not zero it. Secondly the != is conditional as well

Comment: @P__J__ First of all, *clearing* bits was never part of the original code.  If clearing a bit is desired, then `&= ~some_bit` could be used instead.  Secondly, this isn't about removing *conditionals*, it's about removing *branches*.  Also, if `INPUT_n` happens to be a proper boolean already, then then `!=` can go away.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop. You can use *for* loop, *while* loop or *do while* loop according to your need. A *for* loop is more common.

```
int i; 
for(i=1;i<=Number_Of_times_following_code_need_to_run;i++)
{
   \\Your_desired_code_here
}
```

After you added more of current code structure:-

```
  for(i=0;i<40;i++) \\40_is_your_array_length_by_your_code
   {
     if(INPUT_ARRAY[i] != 0){
       output_x |= some_bit
      }
   }
```

Comment: Aside: Loop is a good idea.  More idiomatic to start at 0 and limit with `i< Number_Of_times_following_code_need_to_run`

Comment: In my  code, I always start my loop at 0, never used 1 at start. But I thought starting with 1 will be more meaningful for @ConductedForce

Comment: Unfortunately a loop in this fashion wouldn't work well. The current logic loop is merely to test the hardware we are working with. I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Perhaps because there is no arithmetic relationship between `i` and `some_bit` or even `output_x` where I imagine x is a placeholder as it is in `MACRO_X`.  Moreover for `i = 0` the operations differ.  ConductedForce's explanation of why the loop does not work however is unclear. Too much code is elided of "sketched" in the original question.

Comment: In general, using a loop will just add overhead. So it would slow the code down, not speed it up. A loop might help if the code cache is being overtasked. But converting the code to a loop assumes that the `output_x |= some_bit` statement can actually be parameterized for use in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 64-bit mask instead of `uint32_t INPUT_ARRAY[40];`.

Certainly code uses an indexed array for the convenience of setting/clearing.  Instead use a bit mask to improve performance of the *test*, which certainly occurs far more often than set/clear.